# react native : Is it possible to replace 'array[0]' with 'this.state'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to `console.log an array`. Instead of hard coding array number, can I use `this.state`

For example, this would be usual way to console.log an array with a number:

```
console.log(array[2], 'show array number 2')
```

Is there a way I could replace `array[2]`with `this.state.number` ?

I tried this but it won't work.

```
this.state = {
              number:'2'}
console.log(array.this.state.number, 'show array with state')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are list-like objects and arrays are zero-indexed the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1. Using an invalid index number returns undefined. Given the following array

```
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];
```

to print the first element, you'll use index `0`.

```js
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];

console.log(arr[0]);
```

To print any element in the array use any valid index.

```js
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];

console.log(arr[1]);
```

You'll get `undefined` if you use invalid index.

```js
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];

console.log(arr[3]);
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'],
    title: ''
  }

  render() {
    const buttons = this.state.items.map((btn, i) => <button onClick={() => this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        title: prevState.items[i]
      }
    })} key={i}>Item at index {i}</button>)
    return (
      <div>
      <p>{this.state.title}</p>
      {buttons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log dynamically log your array content, try something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { arrayIndex: 0, array: [] };
  }

  upIndex = () => this.setState({ arrayIndex: this.state.arrayIndex + 1 });

  downIndex = () => this.setState({ arrayIndex: this.state.arrayIndex - 1 });

  render () {
    console.log(this.state.array[this.state.arrayIndex]);
    return (<div>...</div>);
  }
}
```

Note: You can hook `upIndex` and `downIndex` to buttons `onClick` callback to change `arrayIndex` and be careful to check for index out of range.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
this.setState({
    number: 2
}, () =>{
    console.log(array[this.state.number], 'show array with state')
})
```